# Show article only in popup using Joomla with actual template

Tags: templates, joomla, popup, components

I'm using Joomla 3.4 and want to open popup with some article only.
I have this link to load into popop: `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=13&Itemid=176&id=6&tmpl=component`
I know that I must add `tmpl=component` but when I add this it load system CSS, JS and HTML layout. It doesn't load active template CSS, JS etc. Why is this happening? Without this attribute it load whole page with active template.

Thanks for advice.

Never mind! I have already done this. I just need to edit component.php file in template.

Comment: can you provide a link or the template name?

Comment: I have already solve this by editing the component.php file in the template root.

Comment: If you have found the answer to the problem, you could post it as an answer and accept it for further reference.

Comment: Of cource, I just create file named 'component.php' in the template root folder and edit it as I want. I include my CSS, JS, etc to the file with my specific HTML. So if I add `tmpl=component` to the URL it looks for compoment.php file. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the solution.
I just create file named 'component.php' in the template root folder and edit it as I want. I include my CSS, JS, etc to the file with my specific HTML. So if I add `tmpl=component` to the URL it looks for compoment.php file. That's all.